# Ability to change the websites css from an inbuilt style selecting tool

Tags: html, css

I want to create a tool as shown [here](http://ethemes.com/demo/Enzyme/) where the user is able to change the style of the webpage dynamically.

I've searched around but am still not entirely sure on how I could do this.

Any direction on where to look to achieve something like this would be very appreciated!

[image: style switcher]

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific what you mean by tools? If you can provide a clear and concise description of what you'd like to do - we will be able to better help you! :)

Comment: about the link I give above, the link had a style switcher that's i dunno how to add,

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create some way for the user to select the colour they want to use in the interface, and then store that value in a string, for example "userColour". You need to make sure it's a valid CSS colour value, so either '#33aa55' or 'green' (check the CSS reference for named colours which would be easier for you to implement).

If you define the HTML of the page using classes or IDs on the divs and spans etc. that the page is made up of, like this:

```
<div class="myColour"> your content </div>
```

or

```
<div id="myColour"> your content </div>
```

Then you can use Javascript to change the css attributes like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myColour").style.background-color = userColour;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myColour").style.background-color = userColour;
```

For class and id respectively.

You could also use something like jQuery which would give you much better browser compatibility and ease of DOM manipulation to apply styles to your markup dynamically, but the principles are the same.